# DLL load failed during import of cv2

Tags: opencv3.0

I have one error in openCV...
hope you will help me out into this...

C:\Users\nisarg\Desktop\Autoattendance-Cognitive-master\Autoattendance-Cognitive-master>python add_student.py

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "add_student.py", line 1, in 
>       import cv2
>       # openCV
>     File "C:\Users\nisarg\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cv2__init__.py", line 3, in
>    `<module>`
>       from .cv2 import *
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

C:\Users\nisarg\Desktop\Autoattendance-Cognitive-master\Autoattendance-Cognitive
-master>

> DLL error while running my project with opencv

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you are using windows 10 N distribution, the N distributions does not come pre installed with windows media feature pack, which is required after OpenCV version 3.4 and onwards.

The preferred solution is to install the feature pack at : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack

Be careful to choose the version that works with your current version of windows.

If that is not an option, fall back to an earlier version of OpenCV that does not have dll dependencies, you can do that by:`pip install opencv-python=3.3.0.9`

That should get the job done.